# magento 2 category and product page displaying blank

Tags: magento2

I have upgraded `Magento` from `2.1.10` to `2.2.5`. First I have upgraded it locally and all things are working in local then I have upload those source code in beta and did following process :

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento i:rei
```

In beta database was of `Magento 2.1.1` but after did above process now my `Magento is 2.2.5`.

All things are working but the Category and Product detail page is not opening. It is showing blank a white page.

I checked error in `var/log` but no error. I have enabled the error in `index.php` but still no luck.

I gave permission to `var` and `generated` directories.

I changed theme to default theme and also tried by disable all extension.

Comment: Did you run di compile?

Comment: Yes I did. But no error

Comment: Can you try reindex once again after doing all these?

Comment: Yes sorry I forget to add but I did it.

Comment: You have to enable developer mode and see what errors are  coming

Comment: Yes developer mode is already enabled.

Comment: uploaded the **product placeholder images** on > Catalog->Product Image Placeholfers->Base/Small/Swatch/Thumbnail done, but no luck. *Any other solution?*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146169)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share with you so It can be helpful for others.

Actually, I am using **porto theme** and the issue is in placeholder image. The name of the images are different than the database.

I re-upload the images and it is working now. But I can't understand why it totally stops the catalog and product page to be run. It should display the error. Anyway, it is working now.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my porto theme on M2 2.2.3, but i dont understand your feedback. You reupload the product images, after the category and product detail pages are working? I have over 200 products, i can`t reupload all images... :-(

Comment: You dont't need to re-upload all product image you just need to re-upload the place holder image

Comment: uploaded the product placeholder images on Catalog->Product Image Placeholfers->Base/Small/Swatch/Thumbnail done, but no luck. Any other solution? https://www.bambi.ch/elastisches-tragetuch-mit-motiv-5-4m-lang.html

Comment: Make sure your theme configuration -> category view -> page layout is correct. like 2 column with left side etc...